Answers that are personal experience: discouraged? How?
I know we discourage questions that are primarily personal experience, but what about answers?  I see them pretty frequently (like the bottom answer here), and to my mind they rarely contribute to the discussion on the level that we're looking for, but I thought I'd ask about a policy.  Is there a specific strategy we're aiming for?  Should they be downvoted or commented upon or what?

Regarding referring to personal experience in answers:
I've seen answers which incorporate personal experience along with stronger scientific sources, resulting in a stronger, more palpable answer overall. However, I have yet to encounter a valid answer which solely refers to personal experience. In essence, this would also contradict the Q&A format, since questions which elicit highly subjective answers are not a good fit for it. Personal experience does just that: report on one specific personal experience. Especially on a more scientific Q&A site as CogSCi, this does not warrant an answer.
Regarding the specific post you are referring to, ... I just commented on it since it was a new user obviously not aware about SE's Q&A format, and deleted the answer after it got flagged. The Q&A format mandates an answer should answer the question. The post you were referring to did not answer the question at all.
